# Mysql UPDATE inserts a row instead of updating

Tags: mysql, sql-update

We have a legacy query that (simplified) looks like this

```
UPDATE companies_lists_companies, 
       (SELECT c_l_c.id 
        FROM   companies_lists_companies AS c_l_c 
        LIMIT  1) AS list_company 
SET    companies_lists_companies.user_id = 36, 
       companies_lists_companies.companies_list_id = 9 
WHERE  companies_lists_companies.id = list_company.id
```

This inserts a row in table1 instead of updating one. How can that be?

I'm actually not sure right now what the query is meant to do, but I'm curious what would make an UPDATE query insert a row.

Comment: Check whether there is a trigger on table1.

Comment: @MartinK. There are no triggers

Comment: Can you post the subquery too. Some sample data may also be helpful, especially the row which is inserted.

Comment: @MartinK. Updated the question with the real simplified query

Comment: Ok, so you basically choose some random row from companies_lists_companies and update it. What happes if you don't use the subquery and write `WHERE companies_list_companies.id=<choose a value>`instead?